# Making these tooltips supported in IE and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for someone to help me make these tooltips work in IE and Opera.
They are currently powered by CSS and jQuery.

According to my tests, in IE 10 - 8: The tooltips show on hover, but they do not have the same styling as in modern / other browsers.
And, in IE 7 - 6 : The tooltips show before the user hovers on the corresponding link / trigger.
And then nothing happens in Opera.

I would greatly appreciate any help getting this looking the same and working the same in as many browsers as possible. Whether that be with alternative CSS or jQuery or JS, I just need this to work for a project I am working on.

Here the tooltips are: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/CSS3Tooltips/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
>   index.html

You should be using HTTPS for all of your resources, or none of them, but don't mix-and-match.

---

EDIT: I manually inserted a `<div class="tooltip">Text goes here</div>` element onto the page, and I can assure you that it works in IE10 and IE9 as you want it to, however IE8 and below `border-radius` and `box-shadow` are not supported.